# What is the fastest bus?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Which bus is the fastest in *GTA V*? When I'm playing with friends, it takes me too long to get to waypoints in the current bus I use.

Comment: Try the bus zard :v

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest bus in *GTA V* story mode and *GTA Online* is the **[Dashound](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Dashound)**. The second fastest is the [Prison Bus](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Prison_Bus), while the [Bus](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Bus#Grand_Theft_Auto_V_and_Grand_Theft_Auto_Online_2) / [Airport Bus](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Airport_Bus), [Rental Shuttle Bus](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Rental_Shuttle_Bus), [Tourbus](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Tour_Bus) are all tied at third. (Note: The Airport Bus is a 'Bus' variant — they have the exact same stats.) The slowest bus is the [Festival Bus](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Festival_Bus) (a GTA Online vehicle; it can be spawned in story mode only if the game is modded).

The buses' top speed stats:

| Rank | Bus | Top Speed (Broughy) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dashound | 71.75 mph (115.47 km/h) |
| 2 | Prison Bus | 65.25 mph (105.01 km/h) |
| 3 | Bus / Airport Bus, Rental Shuttle Bus, Tourbus | 65.00 mph (104.61 km/h) |
| 4 | Festival Bus | 59.75 mph (96.16 km/h) |

This is according to vehicle top speed testing by [Broughy](https://gtacars.net/gta5/tiers), who [tests vehicle top speed](https://gtacars.net/gta5/topspeed) by driving them on a straight road. Broughy's testing takes the game's physics into account, as opposed to just getting the speed stat from the game files which is less indicative of actual top speed.

[Broughy also tests lap times by driving vehicles on a track.](https://gtacars.net/gta5/laptime) Alongside speed, this also takes the vehicle stats: acceleration, handling, traction, braking, weight, among other stats, into consideration. The bus with the fastest lap time is the **[Rental Shuttle Bus](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Rental_Shuttle_Bus).**

The buses are listed in order here according to lap times, from fastest to slowest:

| Rank | Bus | Lap Time (Broughy) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rental Shuttle Bus | 1:46.672 |
| 2 | Tourbus | 1:46.705 |
| 3 | Bus / Airport Bus | 1:57.427 |
| 4 | Dashound | 1:58.652 |
| 5 | Prison Bus | 2:00.822 |
| 6 | Festival Bus | 2:08.471 |

Sources:

- [Broughy - GTA 5 Vehicle Info, Performance & Tier Lists](https://gtacars.net/gta5/tiers)
- [Broughy's top speed testing methodology](https://gtacars.net/gta5/topspeed)
- [Broughy's lap time testing methodology](https://gtacars.net/gta5/laptime)

Comment: Holy crap this was 7 years ago and I was a 9 year old kid at the time. I even forgot that I made this thread/post lol.

Answer (score 2):

There's really only [3 busses](http://gtaa.info/vehicles/service/) in the game, and their speeds all top out at 540 - the generic "Bus" slightly edging out the other two in breaking. The smaller Rental Shuttle Bus / Tourbus are slightly faster at 590. There is also the [Police Prison Bus](http://gtaa.info/vehicles/emergency/), but that is slower than all the others at 490.

If you need to get places quicker, I'd suggest something that isn't a bus (Unless some mission/heist requires a bus?). They are big and heavy, but not fast.

Comment: What are the units for those speed figures?

Comment: @Ricardo I'm not entirely sure what they translate to in terms of MpH/KpH. I have seen other sites express speed ratings as 0-10 with two decimal places (540 becomes 5.40), and they all tend to top out at 1000 (or 10.00). Most high-end sports/supers have speed ratings in the 800-860 range, and the [only things faster tend to be airplanes](http://gtaa.info/vehicles/all/).